# The SPARK_HOME env variable is set but Jupyter Notebook doesn't see it. (Windows)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm on Windows 10. I was trying to get Spark up and running in a Jupyter Notebook alongside Python 3.5. I installed a pre-built version of Spark and set the SPARK_HOME environmental variable. I installed findspark and run the code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

I receive a Value error:

> ValueError: Couldn't find Spark, make sure SPARK_HOME env is set or Spark is in an expected location (e.g. from homebrew installation).

However the SPARK_HOME variable is set. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1oxae74d9bsoz6x/env_var.png?dl=0) is a screenshot that shows that the list of environmental variables on my system.

Has anyone encountered this issue or would know how to fix this? I only found an old discussion in which someone had set SPARK_HOME to the wrong folder but I don't think it's my case.

Comment: I don't see the list of your environment variables in the screenshot you posted. Can you edit the image to highlight them so it's easier to find them.

Comment: Dear dmlicht, you are very right, it was not there! May have been an issue of taking a screenshot in Windows... [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1oxae74d9bsoz6x/env_var.png?dl=0) is a link to an image with the env variables. Thank you for spotting this!

(I have also tried to do this with SPARK_HOME as a user variable rather than system variable but it didn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem and had it solved by installing "vagrant" and "virtual box". (Note, though I use Mac OS and Python 2.7.11)

Take a look at this tutorial, which is for the Harvard CS109 course : 
https://github.com/cs109/2015lab8/blob/master/installing_vagrant.pdf

After "vagrant reload" on the terminal , I am able to run my codes without errors. 
NOTE the difference between the result of command "os.getcwd" shown in the attached images.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I'd be interested in knowing how to do this purely on Windows (i.e. without a virtual box) but will accept your response as the answer in a couple of days if nobody else responds.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem and wasted a lot of time. I found two solutions:

There are two solutions

1. copy downloaded spark folder in somewhere in C directory and give the link as below

   ```
   import findspark
   findspark.init('C:/spark')
   ```
2. use the function of findspark to find automatically the spark folder

   ```
   import findspark
   findspark.find()
   ```

Comment: How can I find the Spark folder?

Comment: @Hamideh it depends on how you've installed it. You can install it from the spark home page, or use a package manager to install it (i.e. homebrew with macOS). Wherever it is installed, just use the filepath as an environment variable in your system or use the findspark solution

Answer (score 5):

The environmental variables get updated only after system reboot. It works after restarting your system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when installing spark using `pip install pyspark findspark` in a conda environment.

The solution was to do this:

```
export /Users/pete/miniconda3/envs/cenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/
jupyter notebook
```

You'll have to substitute the name of your conda environment for `cenv3` in the command above.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the system after setting up the environmental variables worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem, i solved it by closing cmd then open again. i forget that after editing env variable on windows that should restart cmd..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Initially, I had stored my Spark folder in the Documents directory. Later, when I moved it to the Desktop, it suddenly started recognizing all the system variables and it ran findspark.init() without any error.

Try it out once.

Comment: This should be a comment if it is a "try this", as opposed to when answering it should be, "This will definitely work"

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur, if you don't set the environment variables in .bashrc file. Set your python environment variable as follows:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/python:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way i found to use spark with jupyter notebook is

1- download spark

2- unzip to desired location

3- open jupyter notebook in usual way nothing special

4- now run the below code

```
import findspark
findspark.init("location of spark folder ")

# in my case it is like 

import findspark
findspark.init("C:\\Users\\raj24\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is using a newer Spark version (3.4.1): Make sure to include the "libexec" folder in your init() statement:

```
findspark.init("/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.4.1/libexec/")
```