# Unable to set sparks home in Jupiter notebook- anaconda

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Jupiter Notebook in Anaconda.

I have managed to install pyspark and findpyspark.

I am now using the code: `SPARK_HOME  = C:\spark\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7` to set sparks home.

However, I get the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-27-2126598a4c18>", line 1
    SPARK_HOME  = C:\spark\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify Spark_Home as a string

```
SPARK_HOME  = "C:\spark\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7"
```

This resolves the error you had in your post. For the next error (you shared in the comment) it's similar to: [The SPARK_HOME env variable is set but Jupyter Notebook doesn't see it. (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411914/the-spark-home-env-variable-is-set-but-jupyter-notebook-doesnt-see-it-windows)

Comment: after doing that, do I still need to use findspark.init()?

Comment: ValueError: Couldn't find Spark, make sure SPARK_HOME env is set or Spark is in an expected location (e.g. from homebrew installation).

Comment: So the first command was to resolve your first error. The second you need to check your file systems and your path to find the absolute path to your spark files. I updated my post because your error is similar to an old post.